# quiero hacer una consulta con el resultado de otra consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy haciendo un sistema con php+mysql y me falta solamente resolver un inconveniente para finalizar. lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: tengo una tabla llamada transacciones, que muestra en una columna, una cantidad de pesos colombianos guardados anteriormente. Necesito sumar esa cantidad de pesos colombianos POR CADA USUARIO EN ESPECIFICO GUARDADO EN OTRA TABLA. cabe resaltar de que en la tabla transacciones, creé una columna con el nombre de usuario y asi puedo ver que usuario hizo cual transacción.

```
$consultad="SELECT * FROM transacciones WHERE id2='2' AND nombre='**luis**";


        $resultadod=mysqli_query($mysqli,$consultad);
        echo mysqli_error();

 $numd=mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
         if($numd != 0) { 
         while($filad=mysqli_fetch_array($resultadod)){

      echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>".$q=$filad['nombre']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$filad['pesos']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$filad['entrega']."</td>";

       echo "</tr>";

}

       mysqli_free_result($resultadod);


    }else {  

    echo "No existen registros";

}
```

puedo consultar los pesos que ha gastado el usuario luis, y posteriormente sumarlos si yo quiero, ahora el problema es que quiero hacer lo mismo segun los usuarios que esten guardados en otra tabla.. habrá alguna manera? gracias! cualquier consejo o ayuda será bien recibida

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Para que tu pregunta reciba una mejor respuesta, incluye la estructura de las tablas involucradas. Edita tu pregunta y añade esa información, procurando siempre que sea como texto y no como imágenes (para que otros puedan replicar tu problema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira te estas complicando la vida. Solo tienes que hacer 2 cosas (usar el método `SUM` y el método `GROUP BY`). Las puedes hacer en un solo `SELECT`.

```
SELECT nombreusuario, SUM(valor_transacciones)
  FROM transacciones
 GROUP BY idusuario
 ORDER BY nombreusuario
```

Supongamos que la fila del valor de las transacciones se llame *valor_transacciones* y que cada usuario tenga una fila con un *idusuario* como `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

ok. Muy facil. si lo que quieres es identificar cuales transferencias son positivas ( Me imagino que seran los ingresos) y las negativas (supongo que son los gastos).

Es mejor que modifiques o crees una tabla nueva en el que tengas

> - id_transacciones (Como primary key)
> - valor_transacciones
> - nombre_usuario
> - tipo_transacción

Con el tipo_transaccion podras identificar si es un ingreso o un gasto.  De esta forma, al momento de hacer la consulta seleccionas que te muestre solo los valores de las transacciones tipo positivo y en otra consulta los tipo negativos.

En este caso ya no puedes usar WHERE. sino HAVING, mas o menos así

```
SELECT nombreusuario, SUM(valor_transacciones)

  FROM transacciones

 GROUP BY idusuario

HAVING tipo_transaccion = positivo

 ORDER BY nombreusuario
```

Comment: eso es exactamente lo que hice, yo tengo una columna igual a la que tu llamas tipo_transaccion con los valores "Compra" o "Venta" y yo diferencio si se suma o se resta a partir de ahi. todo bien hasta ahi, pero como hago para restar los resultados de esa consulta, con los resultados de otra consulta? sabiendo que tengo que realizar la operacion con cada usuario en especifico.  por ejemplo: el resultado del total de compras de orlando - el resultado del total de ventas de orlando.

Comment: el otro problema es que despues tengo que sumar: el total de compras y ventas de orlando, (salio negativo)  y luego sumar el total de compras y ventas de karen (salio positivo) + el total de compras y ventas de nelson (salio positivo)

Comment: y luego guardar cada resultado en una variable para utilizarla posteriormente...

Comment: Para eso tendrías que tener 2 tablas.  En una tabla tienes los valores de los ingresos, y en otra tabla los valores de los gastos o compras. y combinas las tablas con LEFT JOIN.

Comment: La idea es que aprendas. Lee la siguiente guía. esta en ingles así que tendrás que traducirlo. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: @LuisMaldonado si esta respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, debería [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).